# Plotting Function Syms over [-2,7] in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot graph and point of data. I have tried to make MATLAB code as below.

```
clear;clc;
syms x;
f=-5/21*x^2+31/21*x+19/7;
xi=[6 -1 3];
yi=[3 1 5];
fig=ezplot(f);
set(fig,'color','r','linewidth',2);
hold on;
plot(xi,yi,'p','markersize',15,'markerfacecolor','y','markeredgecolor','b','linewidth',2,'markersize',10);
axis([min(xi)-1 max(xi)+1 min(yi)-1 max(yi)+1]);
grid on;
```

and the result as below.
[image]

Why the graph of quadratic equation can't plotted over x in -2 into 7? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `ezplot` allows you to set the interval for the x-axis. You can do it like so:

```matlab
syms x;
f=-5/21*x^2+31/21*x+19/7;
fig=ezplot(f, [-2,7]);
```

Matlab suggests you use `fplot` instead, which you can easily substitute.

```matlab
syms x;
f=-5/21*x^2+31/21*x+19/7;
fig=fplot(f, [-2,7]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `xlim(limits)` as in `xlim([-2 7])` on your plot after they're plotted too.